# Adding an archive button to emails in Inbox

Tags: gmail

Is it somehow possible to add a direct archive button to every individual email in my Gmail inbox overview?

I would like to have this shortcut in order to being able to quickly archive a message instead of having to mark the respective mail first and clicking on the top archive button.

Comment: The **e** keyboard shortcut doesn’t work for you?

Comment: @Alex: It does, thanks for pointing that out. But I still need to mark (tick the box) the respective email. Having a visual button would allow me to simply press the button to archive the message.

Comment: Android's one up on the web interface. I can swipe-to-archive right from the Inbox list. That said, there's nothing within Gmail to do what you want. You'd need to find (or build) a third-party solution that does some JavaScript/CSS trickery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Chrome, then this extension should give you exactly what you want:

[Actions for Gmail™ (beta)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/actions-for-gmail-beta/mclmmkhldnfokbgnhoibcgblghkmncem)

> This is a very simple extension: It places an "archive" or "delete" button next to each message in your Gmail™ inbox.
>
> Now you can archive or delete any message with just one click.

[image: screen shot from Chrome Web Store]

Comment: This is great! Does someone know of a similar add-on for Firefox?